# How to hide the bs-popover based on events

Tags: angularjs, popover

I am using bs-popover to display my contents on click(as a menu) in angularjs. But I need to hide this popover-menu when I click somewhere in the browser window. I want it to be dismissed on that type of event. How can I do that?

Comment: `bs-popover` implies Twitter Bootstrap popover?

Comment: yes. its from bootstrap

Comment: My answer will work for you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write directive for this.

```
yourApp.directive('bndocumentclick',
 function($document,$rootScope,$timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
     link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
        $document.on("click", function(ev) {
           // Do stuff here to remove your popover.
        }
     }
 }
});
```

`HTML`

```
<body bndocumentclick>
```

And

```
<div bs-popover ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">
```

You need to use because you would not like to close your popover whenever user clicks inside popover.

Answer (score 0):

The solution provied by @Jay Shukla doesn't work.

The "$event.stopPropagation()" on the element that triggers the popover doesn't stops it from closing when you make a click inside the popover.. if you have some interaction inside your popover this will be a problem.

This works:

```
angular.module('yourApp')
.directive('closePopovers', function ($document, $rootScope, $timeout) {
return {
  restrict: 'EA',
  link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    $document.on('click', function (ev) {

      var targetElem = angular.element(ev.target);

      if (targetElem.data('toggle') !== 'popover' 
      && targetElem.parents('[data-toggle="popover"]').length === 0 
      && targetElem.parents('.popover').length === 0) {

        $('.popover').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var scope = $this.scope();
            scope.$apply(function () {
              scope.$hide();
            });
          }
        );
      }
    });
  }
};
});
```

On your body:

On your element that triggers the popover:

```
<button data-toggle="popover" [other data elements here] bs-popover>Toggle popover</button>
```